# Not able to fetch the inner node list data from XML using XML Parsing

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-xmlpullparser

I am trying to fetch the FL tag multiple times but when i an trying inner node list it only fetch first item only. For more see my output. This is the XML data i got from web Service

```
<response uri="/ats/private/xml/JobOpenings/getRecords">
    <result>
        <JobOpenings>
            <row no="1">
                <FL val="JOBOPENINGID">
                    <![CDATA[ 100 ]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Published in website">
                    <![CDATA[ true ]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Modified by">
                    <![CDATA[ Admmin ]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Modified time">
                    <![CDATA[ Yesterday ]]>
                </FL>
            </row>
            <row no="2">
                <FL val="JOBOPENINGID">
                    <![CDATA[ 101 ]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Published in website">
                    <![CDATA[ true ]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Modified by">
                    <![CDATA[ Admin ]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Modified time">
                    <![CDATA[ 2 Days Ago ]]>
                </FL>
            </row>
            <row no="3">
                <FL val="JOBOPENINGID">
                    <![CDATA[ 102 ]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Published in website">
                    <![CDATA[ true ]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Modified by">
                    <![CDATA[ Admin ]]>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Modified time">
                    <![CDATA[ 2 Days Ago ]]>
                </FL>
            </row>
        <JobOpenings>
    <result>
</response>
```

And this is the Code i used in my Activity

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(AppConfig.URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("row");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodeList.item(i);

            Element playlistElement = (Element) node;

            NodeList title = playlistElement.getElementsByTagName("FL");

            for (int kl = 0; kl < title.getLength(); kl++) {

                if (title.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0) != null) {

                    Element nameElement = (Element) title.item(0);
                    title = nameElement.getChildNodes();
                    Log.v("name===>", ((Node) title.item(0)).getNodeValue());

                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Here is the Output :

```
12-04 15:56:08.694: V/name===>(3918): JOBOPENINGID  100
12-04 15:56:08.694: V/name===>(3918): JOBOPENINGID  101
12-04 15:56:08.704: V/name===>(3918): JOBOPENINGID  102
12-04 15:56:08.704: V/name===>(3918): JOBOPENINGID  103
12-04 15:56:08.704: V/name===>(3918): JOBOPENINGID  107
12-04 15:56:08.704: V/name===>(3918): JOBOPENINGID  108
12-04 15:56:08.704: V/name===>(3918): JOBOPENINGID  118
12-04 15:56:08.704: V/name===>(3918): JOBOPENINGID  200
```

Help me Please............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don you use [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) for parsing the XML? I have never used your version, but seem to me that `XmlPullParser` will do it's job better, since you tell it to focus on `START_TAG` (for example) and then write the name of the tag you want to be found (*FL in your example*).

What `XPP` will do is, he'll read through entire XML document and search for the given `START_TAG`. Once found, you can do whatever you want with it, inside a `switch` case.

Comment: Thanks! Now I am able to fetch the data from that using XmlPullParser, but still not able to fetch FL tag value

   <FL val="Modified time">
        <![CDATA[ Yesterday ]]>
   </FL>

Now i have just able to fetch "Yesterday" but i also need the value "Modified time".

Comment: Try to fetch the entire TAG (START_TAG) and then do a substring on it, cause he might fetch everything from that TAG.

Comment: To get "something" from `val="something"` use [getAttributeValue(null, "val")](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getAttributeValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) when you're on a `START_TAG` and `getName()` is "FL".

Answer (score 0):

Might be you overwrite title in loop :

```
if (title.item(0).getChildNodes().item(0) != null) {
   Log.v("name===>", ((Node) title.item(0).getChildNodes()).getNodeValue());
}
```